# Is Peter Parker/Spider-Man a stalker in the comics?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, the-amazing-spider-man

In both the 2002-2007 *Spider-Man* trilogy and the newer *Amazing Spider-Man* trilogy, Peter Parker is seen stalking his love interest (Mary Jane and Gwen Stacy, respectively) to an unhealthy degree.

Was this present in the *Spider-Man* comics as well?

Comment: The neighborhood Spider-Man is a little *too* friendly if you ask me...

Comment: To be fair he did start out as a hormonal teenaged boy.

Comment: To be even fairer, the universe loves kicking Peter Parker in the proverbial, and occasionally literal, balls.

Comment: “stalking his love interest... to an unhealthy degree” — that’s why the end credits include a message imploring viewers to please stalk responsibly. It’s terrible when a few weirdos ruing stalking for us normal stalkers.

Comment: He also stalks himself with hidden cameras.

Comment: @Monty129 what, stalkers normally miss the adolescent hormone surges on your planet?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. He often surprised them by showing up out of nowhere.

Of course, stealth is his modus operandi. He often spies on bad guys, either to take pictures for the *Daily Bugle*, or to be able to beat them as Spider-Man. This seems to have become second nature to him, carrying over into his private life.

I remember him secretly snapping pictures of Mary Jane. (I'll see if I can find an example).

Comment: Which is doubly weird, since MJ knew about him being _Spider-Man_ almost since the beginning (or was that ret-conned or re-ret-conned??) - so she must have been aware of him at least being able to do it. Maybe she even gave him the opportunities "totally by accident". Getting your picture taken, not that bad an idea for an aspiring actress...

Comment: Yeah, that she knew almost from the beginning was ret-conned, when that story was printed where she tells she knew almost from the beginning, she never knew in the comics from the beginning. (Untill it was ret-conned many many years and comics later)